# Calculate the days between two fields in sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

How to calculate number of days between two date fields of same module without counting the weekends (Saturday and Sunday) using the "Formula Builder" in sugarCRM studio.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculated field in sugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074590/calculated-field-in-sugarcrm)

Comment: @Reisclef I'd say it's the other way around, considering that this is older (and also more descriptive/correct)

Comment: @Jay I have to admit I wasn't sure which would be best placed as a duplicate. I may have even meant to suggest the other!

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary remarks**

As far as I'm aware Sugar Logic doesn't have a function to count the days of a date span.
However we can calculate it using existing Sugar functions like this:

```
add(1,subtract(daysUntil(addDays($date_end,365000)),daysUntil(addDays($date_start,365000))))
```

This will return the span from $date_start and $date_end, counting **all** days, including both start and end date,
so the span 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-01 will return 1 rather than 0.

Notes:

- This does not handle the special cases of any of those fields being empty.
- If you want to display the result of this formula directly, wrap it in floor() to display as an integer without `.000000`

**The solution**

Since Sugar Logic also does **not** seem to provide any *modulo* function and formula scoped variables either,
the resulting formula for what you want (count only Mo-Fr) is as "compact" as:

```
floor(add(0.5,
  add(
    multiply(floor(divide(add(1,subtract(daysUntil(addDays($date_end,365000)),daysUntil(addDays($date_start,365000)))),7)),5)
  ,
    add(
      min(
        max(0,subtract(6,ifElse(equal(dayofweek($date_start),0),7,dayofweek($date_start))))
      ,
        subtract(
          add(1,subtract(daysUntil(addDays($date_end,365000)),daysUntil(addDays($date_start,365000))))
        ,
          multiply(floor(divide(add(1,subtract(daysUntil(addDays($date_end,365000)),daysUntil(addDays($date_start,365000)))),7)),7)
        )
      )
    ,
      max(
        0,
        subtract(
          subtract(
            add(1,subtract(daysUntil(addDays($date_end,365000)),daysUntil(addDays($date_start,365000))))
          ,
            multiply(floor(divide(add(1,subtract(daysUntil(addDays($date_end,365000)),daysUntil(addDays($date_start,365000)))),7)),7)
          )
        ,
          subtract(8,ifElse(equal(dayofweek($date_start),0),7,dayofweek($date_start)))
        )
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Notes:

- The formulas above do not handle start dates that are *after* the end date, you could catch such cases using `if()` and `isAfter()`
- Holidays and such are **not** considered at all, so this will **not** only count actual work days